# Анализ произведения

Tags: правила

Есть какой то лайфхак, для анализа призведения по литературе?Второй раз сдаю и все отклоняют и возвращают на доработку

Answer (score 1):

Я придерживалась плана учителя, нам  объясняли прям на уроке и разбирали с примерами, еще учитель скидывала ссылку с теорией, как [правильно делать анализ](https://studwork.org/spravochnik/polezno/analiz-proizvedeniya-po-literature). Придерживались этого  и было нормально.